# WS Tech USB-DVI Graphics Driver Blue Tinge

Tags: windows-7, usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a WS TEch USB-DVI graphics unit which connects one of my monitors to my computer over USB. It has been working fine for the better part of 3 years but today when I started my computer up I have found that it has a blue tinge on the screen now. The blue tinge only affects the monitor connected through the device and none of the other monitors which are connected through internal graphics cards.

**Tests I Have Done**

- Connected to a different monitor
- Checked colour settings on screen (all normal)
- Checked Colour Management and tried adjusting the colour profile to match one of the other monitors and then restarted the machine
- Disable WS Tech and then re-enable it
- Check driver version (up to date)

It looks similar to what is displayed if a monitor is set to show cool but the monitor is definitely set to normal.

## Update #1

I have tried connecting the monitor in question to an alternate computer and the blue tinge wasn't there, it was displaying perfectly so that tends to tell me that the issue is only on the display output for the WS Tech module, just don't know where the issue could be at this point.

Comment: This seems to be a USB 2.0 device, correct? What screen resolution do you use?

Comment: Correct USB2.0, resolution 1680x1050

Comment: As a test I just tried reducing the resolution from 1680x1050 to 1280x1024 which is what Windows 7 shows as the recommended resolution and it made no difference.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that the same WS TEch USB-DVI adapter with the same monitor works fine on other computers?

Comment: Also, what does "blue tinge" mean? Does it happen on the entire screen? Did you try to output some standard color palette (stripes) to see which color is missing, or else?

Comment: I haven't tested the whole adapter on another computer just the monitor as it can be a pain to setup and install it on another computer. "blue tinge" means that the whole affected screen is shaded blue like someone has put a blue filter over the whole screen. I can see clearly what is on the screen, there is no blurring or affect to the quality of the image on the screen, it is just shaded blue over the normal colour of the element.

Comment: Are you using digital (DVI) section of the output, or VGA (analog section) for your display? So far it looks like you are using analog signaling, and one of color channel is broken.

Comment: The device only has a DVI output but the screen only supports VGA so I have a DVI to VGA passive adaptor connected between the monitor cable and the WS Tech adaptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the torture of OP and extracting true information with questions, the answer is: Your device has DVI-I - integrated digital and analog interface. With the adapter, you are using the analog part of the connector. The massive uniform color distortion (imbalance) means that one (or more) analog channels are deteriorated and have reduced amplitude (or completely lost), due to electrical fatigue or bent (or contaminated) analog pin. Or internal malfunction of the analog channel. Or your broken DVI-to-VGA "adapter".

Try to connect a true DVI monitor to determine if the digital logic of the device is ok. And move away form the VGA standard, you will have much better image quality. Monitors are very cheap these days.

Comment: I went for that and connected a true DVI monitor and had no issues at all. Thanks.